# varbinary to literal varchar copy in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, binary

How can I get from this SQL Server varbinary:

```
0x63C34D6BCAD555EB64BF7E848D02C376
```

To this varchar?

```
'63C34D6BCAD555EB64BF7E848D02C376'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
declare @B varbinary(max) = 0x63C34D6BCAD555EB64BF7E848D02C376
declare @C varchar(35)

set @C = stuff(upper(sys.fn_varbintohexstr(@B)), 1, 2, '')

select @C
```

Result:

```
63C34D6BCAD555EB64BF7E848D02C376
```